# Can multi openseaSDK.createSellOrder() by using promise all?

Tags: nft, opensea

I want to create multi openseaSDK.createSellOrder() by using Promise.all() but get an error: "Duplicate order". Anyone used to it? Help me please...

i just awaited one by one but sometimes still get error: "Duplicate order". i dont now how to control this :(((